# Insert value in a text field using Ruby - watir/selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, textbox, numbers, watir

I am trying to insert a number in the 'Mine Id' using Ruby - Watir/Selenium
Somehow the field `<input>` field is not being recognized as a text box and hence I am unable to enter values through the code.

The id 'inputdrs' is used multiple times on the same page.

Any suggestions how to achieve it.
The URL is this

http://www.msha.gov/drs/drshome.htm

The below don't work:

```
@browser.text_field(:id => /inputdrs/, :index => 2).set("3607277")

browser.text_field(:name, "inputdrs").set("3607277")
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: How are they not working?  Is there an exception, or does nothing happen?  If there is an exception, could you edit your post and add it?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The solutions work. I was able to insert a number in the mine id. But now I am not able to click on the 'Search' button next to it.                                                                     $browser.button(:src,"http://www.msha.gov/drs/images/getinfonew.jpg").click              Sorry I dont mean to ask trivial questions, but this worked earlier yesterday on IE. Plus I am getting this from Test Wise Recorder on FF.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

$browser = Watir::Browser.start "http://www.msha.gov/drs/drshome.htm"

a = 0
b = $browser.text_fields.length 
while a < b
  $browser.text_fields[a].set a
  a += 1
end
```

This will put the value of a in each text field on this page. I REALLY drew out the loop so you can see whats going on. This isn't as dynamic as you would like it, but if the page has the same amount of text_fields you should be fine.

OR you can do something like..

```
$browser.text_field(:name => "MineId").select
$browser.send_keys "hello"
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. Looks like IE and FF respond differently. I tried this solution on my laptop at home on FF and it works. I will check again on my work PC in office on IE on Monday and let you know whether it works :)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The html of the Mine ID field is:

```
<input size="8" maxlength="8" name="MineId" onclick="this.value='';" id="inputdrs" align="middle" type="number">
```

The line:

```
@browser.text_field(:id => /inputdrs/, :index => 2).set("3607277")
```

Will fail because it is inputting into the wrong text field. If you get all of the text fields with that id:

```
browser.text_fields(:id => 'inputdrs').collect(&:name)
#=> ["q", "MineId", "OperSearch", "MineName", "CntctrId", "CntCtrSearch", "Controller"]
```

You can see it is the second field. However, because Watir is using a 0-based index, you actually get the OperSearch field. This would have worked by using an `:index => 1` instead.

The line:

```
browser.text_field(:name, "inputdrs").set("3607277")
```

Will fail because the "inputdrs" is the value of the id attribute and not the name attribute.

**Solution**

Given that the id attribute value is not unique for this page, you should probably not use it for locating. Instead, use something unique, such as the name attribute.

```
browser.text_field(:name => "MineId").set("3607277")
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. Looks like IE and FF respond differently. I tried this solution on my laptop at home on FF and it works. I will check again on my work PC in office on IE on Monday and let you know whether it works :)